# Return a list containing flowables in python

Tags: python, list, function, pdf, reportlab

I have a piece of code which generates some data (Paragraph and Table) which will eventually go into a pdf. I am generating this pdf using the [reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/) in python.

Now, I have to run this function over say, 10 files. The results should finally go into one pdf document. One way of doing this is, to run this function 10 times in a loop, generate 10 pdfs using reportlib and then combine them using [pyPdf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyPdf). I dont like this!

Instead, I am returning the list from the function into my main function and appending it to a list at the end of every loop. I am then trying to build the final pdf in the main function, but it does not seem to work. Here's the code in main:

```
doc = SimpleDocTemplate("%s/taxonomy_report.pdf" %(path), pagesize=letter)
final_table = [] 
for folders in range(0,11):
     a=taxonomy_function(path,folders)
     final_table.append(a)

 doc.build(final_table)
```

Now, in the function taxonomy_function, I have the following..

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle, Paragraph, Spacer
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

elements = [] #Keep appending whatever you want to add to the pdf

styleH = styles["Heading2"]
p = Paragraph('''Multiple-bit error/fault classification''', styleH)
elements.append(p)
t1=Table(data_FF)
elements.append(t1)
return elements
```

Now, in the main function, if I check the contents of final_table, it was empty! That is, the variable 'a' contained an empty list in main() everytime the taxonomy_function() was called.

```
Final elements is [[], [], [], [], [], None, [], [], [], [], []]
```

Ok, somehow the returning issue got sorted..
Now, I cant do doc.build(final_table).But, I can do doc.build(final_table[0]), doc.build(final_table[1](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/)) etc., And if I do doc.build() in a loop, it will rewrite the previous data and I will left with the last entry only. Is there a way to write the list of lists in my final table to pdf at one go using doc.build(final_table)? Python errors out when I do this.

```
File "python_taxonomy_all_examples.py", line 51, in <module>
    doc.build(final_table)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/platypus/doctemplate.py", line 1117, in build
    BaseDocTemplate.build(self,flowables, canvasmaker=canvasmaker)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/platypus/doctemplate.py", line 880, in build
    self.handle_flowable(flowables)
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with how you return the list, but it seems that your taxonomy function is not working correctly. Have you separately tested this function? If it returns `None`, it contains a code path that doesn't explicitly terminate. Where is the rest of the function?

Comment: The function is about 400 lines long.. So, I did not post the entire function. It works fine individually..

Comment: If it works individually, returning a non-empty list, then you aren't calling it correctly; check the arguments with `print` before you call it.

Comment: I just edited my post to show the outputs inside the function and main()

Comment: Never mind.. I am not sure how, but it seems to work now!

Comment: I now face the issue of printing a list of lists to pdf.. any way out?

Answer (score 0):

If i see this correctly you are passing a nested list to `doc.build()`. This may be the problem. Instead of appending a list *into* another list, you have to concatenate them:

change `final_table.append(a)` to `final_table = final_table + a`

You should than have a full story which can be build with a single call to `doc.build()`